# Bad: Flutter downloading problems

Tags: flutter, download

So I extracted the files in the C: drive (not the program files) and added C:\flutter\src\bin in the Path variable and when I run flutter --version in cmd it gives an error..please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please expand on your question. Include the error message etc.

Answer (score 0):

It could be great to see what the error is.